# Responsive hover for responsive image

Tags: image, css, hover

how to do responsive hover?

This is good hover example and it's perfectly fits for my screen size [image: good example] and this is bad not responsive hover example[image: bad example]

## This is my code

**HTML**

```
  <div class="product-img-list">
    <%= link_to product_path(product), class: 'product_link' do %>
    <%= image_tag(product.image_url, class: "img-responsive",  size: "300x250") %>
    <% end %>
    <span class="product-img-text"><span>code</span></span>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
span.product-img-text {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table;
  height: 80px;
  left: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 230px;
  width: 291px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
}

.product-img-list:hover span.product-img-text {
  opacity: 1;
}

span.product-img-text span {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.img-responsive {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.product-img-list.img-responsive {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

Thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that you must make the `.product-img-text` be responsive (*instead of using hardcoded dimensions*)

something like the following

```
span.product-img-text {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table;
  position: absolute;

  height: 25%; /*assuming text is not that much*/
  left: 1em; /*to account for margin*/
  right:1em /*to account for margin*/
  bottom: 0; /*add it to bottom of image*/

  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
}
```

and you will have to make `.product-img-list` be `realtive` positioned if it is not.

```
.product-img-list{position:relative}
```